# How to connect 2 laptops to same SQL Developer database?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, database-connection

We don't know how to connect 2 PC's to the same SQL Developer database/server in order to use it simultaneously.

Comment: Because we use Oracle SQL Developer

Comment: SQL Developer database…? Is that just regular Oracle SQL Server or something I'm unfamiliar with?
Is the database located on one of the pc's or on some other server?
Can you connect from a single pc at a time and unable to connect using two pc's?
Can you initiate two sessions from single machine to said server?

Comment: Oracle SQL Developer is not a database.https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/12/i-have-oracle-sql-developer-installed-now-what/

Answer (score 0):

Look u are probably making a mistake here. Sql developer isnt a Database its just an IDE to manage a database for example an Oracle Database.
If u need to connect multiple pCs to the same database,you need to have some kind of client server communication. e.g: Pc 1 has the database setup in it, now pc2 and pc3 wants to connect to the same database that is sitting inside pc1. Id recommend write a short server code that uses the database and host it into whatever type of network u are working on. Assuming u just want to connect another pc, a LAN seems fine.Now hit the url from the client pcs and make http requests to the server pc.Define this requests to your liking to make the client pc operate on the server database.

Comment: The idea is ok, but you don't need to set up any services to expose the database to the network. If it's anything but express (I think) it already exposes services on some ports that can be accessed through LAN connection.

Comment: Yes But didnt mention if the person required the other pc to be in LAN only. So, guess i proposed a more generic solution :)

Comment: Ah, that's true :) I Wonder why you were downvoted either way… It's not like your answer isn't correct or is missleading. I sometimes feel like people come in, think 'well I don't get it' and downvote everything

Comment: Thanks for your understanding,and removing the downvote. Really appreciate it <3